# How to listen event dispatched from ANE?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, event-handling, flex4.6, air-native-extension

What the title says.

I have in my native code :

```
freContext.dispatchStatusEventAsync("myEvent","");
```

in the as3 part of the ane :

```
 private static function onStatus( event:StatusEvent ):void {
        if(event.code == MyEvent.EVENT_NAME){ // EVENT_NAME = "myEvent"
            displayToast("dispatching event");
            dispatcher.dispatchEvent(MyEvent(MyEvent.EVENT_NAME));
        }
    }
```

and in my flex application (MyAppHomeView.mxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        title="Home View"
        initialize="createListener()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            protected function createListener():void{
                MyANE.showDialogMessage("init");
                addEventListener(MyEvent.EVENT_NAME,handleEvent);
            }

            protected function handleEvent(event:MyEvent):void{
                MyANE.showDialogMessage("myEvent");
            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


</s:View>
```

I do get the "dispatching event" toast (which means the native code part works fine), but not the "myEvent" dialog. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because you subscribe to the current object (instance of **View**) which is not the origin of the event.

Comment: So where should I add the listener? I'm pretty new with flex/as3.

Comment: You should subscribe to the very object that is the source of the event. Maybe that **MyANE**, maybe not. You should read that ANE's manual to learn how to do it because there's no such thing as "common practice" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Organis comment and adobe's example here : https://github.com/nweber/SystemVolumeNativeExtension/blob/master/VolumeTest/src/VolumeTest.mxml I managed to fix my problem :

First MyAne class must extends EventDispatcher.
Then in onStatus :

```
private function onStatus( event:StatusEvent ):void {
    if(event.code == MyEvent.EVENT_NAME){ // EVENT_NAME = "myEvent"
        displayToast("dispatching event");
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.EVENT_NAME));
    }
}
```

and in the mxml, create an instance of MyANE and call addEventListener on it.

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            var ane:MyANE = new MyANE();

            protected function createListener():void{
                MyANE.showDialogMessage("init");
                ane.addEventListener(MyEvent.EVENT_NAME,handleEvent);
            }

            protected function handleEvent(event:MyEvent):void{
                MyANE.showDialogMessage("myEvent");
            }



        ]]>
</fx:Script>
```